# What makes Internet Shortcut files special?

Tags: windows-8.1, shortcuts

When I save a shortcut from Firefox to disk, this is its contents when viewed in a text or hex editor.

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://superuser.com/
IDList=
HotKey=0
IconFile=C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\e8oe2h15.default\shortcutCache\ndPGaHoK9RbB9Xs6pYDwiA==.ico
IconIndex=0
```

It appears very simple: plain text with some markup in a file.

Let's say I want to recreate this file manually.

1. I create an empty text file.
2. I paste the contents above into it.
3. .. save the file and exit the program.
4. .. change the file extension from txt to url.
5. .. accept the risk of loosing file type association by clicking YES
   when prompted.

[image: 1]

Now, I would expect to be able to open this file in my default web browser by double clicking on the file icon. But no, it doesn't work like that. Instead, I receive an error message.

[image: 2]

> The target "" of this Internet Shortcut is not valid. Go to the
>  Internet Shortcut property sheet and make sure the target is correct.

What exactly is meant by `target ""`?

By searching here on the site, I can see that several other users have stumbled upon this or similar difficulties with Internet Shortcut files, and some have even attempted to create "cross platform" Internet Shortcut files. What I don't see is why this is such a pain in the first place.

It's supposed to be just a simple file with a URL address that opens in a web browser. So what makes these "Internet Shortcut" files special? What makes them tick? When I compare my file with the original, they appear to be identical. So where exactly is the problem then?

### Update

---

Here's some interesting findings. The word "target" likely means URL, and "Internet Shortcut property sheet" most probably refers to "Web Document" tab on the file properties dialog box. *If I remember correctly it was titled "Internet Shortcut" in previous versions of Windows (in Windows 98 at least). It appears to have been renamed to Web Document since then.*

There is more to it! As can be seen from the screenshots below, my file shares the same SHA1 digest as the original. But it does not share the same file icon, nor does it have the "Web Document" tab.

[image: original file properties]
[image: new file properties]
[image: original file sha1]
[image: new file sha1]

What's even more is that when I rename my new file so that it begins with an upper case letter, it becomes a functional Internet Shortcut file. Just like that! It just starts working. If I rename it again, so that it starts with a lower case letter, it stops working... again. Don't take my word for it, have a look at the screenshot below.

[image: new file properties with new name]

It also helps starting the file name with an underscore, a dash, a point, a parenthesis, curly brace, square bracket, equal sign, number sign, exclamation mark, and so on. It even properly replaces the globe icon with a blank paper sheet icon. Renaming it to anything other than `test` or `Test` really changes the icon.

But what's causing it to behave or misbehave like this? For instance, why would it matter if the file name begins with an upper case letter? There is no such limitation for regular files...

### Update 2

---

If the new file's name starts with an upper case letter, *prior to changing the name extension*, and **then gets renamed** so that it starts with a lower case letter... then it still works!

So if you go about it like this, it will work:

```
newfile Lancelot.txt
pastein Lancelot.txt
rename Lancelot.txt Lancelot.url
rename Lancelot.url lancelot.url
```

[image: a]
[image: b]

### Update 3

---

It is likely that the original problem with the test.url file occurred at step 4 above. I had initially created a file named test.txt on a different disk and renamed it test.url. This was before I created a second file with the same name on the system disk in Desktop folder (as depicted above). I do not recollect, but it is likely that I initially created a file, changed the name extension, and then pasted in the target URL and saving it and hoping for it to work by a simple double click. As opposed to creating the file, pasting in the target URL, and **then** changing the name extension.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your method. It works here using your copy/paste [aside from a missing icon, of course] - target"" is what should be listed for `URL: ` in Web Document when you open the property sheet… here that correctly shows `http://superuser.com`. I'm testing on WIn7 though, don't have 8.1 to try.

Comment: @Tetsujin Check your file name. Does it start with an upper or lower case letter? If upper case, try lower case. Else... then that's really strange.

Comment: I have one called 'net shortcut.url' & another simply called 'New Text Document` - windows seemingly is hiding the .url even though I have it generally set not to; I did initially change .txt to .url

Comment: Never mind. I lost track of things. I now started off with a `baby boy.txt` file and renamed it to `baby boy.url` and it worked. I renamed it again to say `baby.url` (extension hidden) and it still worked, as did `Baby.url`. I figured it might have to do with using more than one word for name. Now all of a sudden I was able to create a blank `test.txt` and past into that and rename it to `test.url` and it worked. Huh?! I have no idea what's going on here anymore. Behavior appears to vary by the weather. It was sunny before, but clouds are building up now and it might start to rain.

Comment: Just to verify I did a reboot and yes, I can now create `test.txt` and rename it to `test.url` and it will work. Go figure! It would appear that previous "baby boy" in a file name somehow set it straight. Windows got offended?

Comment: I can now even remove all contents from the file `test.url` so that it becomes 0 byte, and it will still work. As long as the name extension is kept and "Web Document" tab is unchanged. This is a sorry excuse for a file type.

Answer (score 9):

I think I got something. As I suspected, Windows somehow internalizes (remembers) the names you have previously used for Internet Shortcut files. I have done some experiments using Windows 10 TP. I will try to sum up what I have learned so far. The screenshot below shows the icons and names of the files I have been experimenting with.

[image: icons]

*I will refer to them by number, from left to right, or by name.*

- Number 1 was created from Firefox by drag and dropping the favicon to
  the desktop. I used this one as a reference. It is working.
- Number 2, 3 and 6 were created manually as blank text files. They
  were left empty and their name extensions changed from txt to url.
  These are **not** working: they cause the error to appear.

  [image: error]
- Number 4 was created manually as a blank text file. The content of
  number 1 was then pasted into it, and its name extension changed
  from txt to url. It is working.
- Number 5 was created manually as a blank text file. Its file type
  name and target URL was typed in manually. It is working.
- Changing the file name (extension excluded) affects the
  function (whether or not it actually works) of the file
  in one of two ways.

> **1:** If the content of the file was properly defined prior to enabling
>   it (by setting url extension), it will not be affected by a name
>   change. It worked before the change, and it will work after the change.
>
> **2:** If the content of the file was **not** defined (e.g. blank file) prior to enabling it, it will **not** be affected by a name
>   change. Changing the name alone won't help. It didn't work before and
>   it won't work after the change. **Additionally!** The new file name
>   will become unusable later on, should you decide to change the file
>   name anyway without properly defining the content (or leaving it
>   blank) and you later on come back to add proper URL definition (read
>   on for explanation).

- Changing the file content affects the function of the file
  in one of two ways.

> **1:** If the content of the file was properly defined previously, the
>   file will still work, as it did before. But all changes made to the
>   file will be ignored. In fact, all content can be removed and the file
>   will still work. To commit any changes the file has to be saved under
>   a new file name, one that has never been used before. Letter casing
>   counts, so making changes to **test.url** and saving it as **Test.url** (if
>   previously unused) is considered a new file, independent of test.url
>   file. Any additional changes will have to be saved under yet another
>   file name, one never used before. So on and so forth.
>
> **2:** If the content of the file was **not** defined previously (e.g. blank file), it won't help defining it now by making changes to the
>   content and saving these changes. All changes will be ignored. If it
>   didn't work before, it won't work after the changes. To commit any
>   changes, the file must be saved under a new file name, one that has
>   never been used before (a new file with unique new name).

### File contents

Contents of number 1, 2, 6:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://superuser.com/
IDList=
HotKey=0
IconFile=C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\bcf6rzuf.default\shortcutCache\ndPGaHoK9RbB9Xs6pYDwiA==.ico
IconIndex=0
```

Contents of number 3 and 4: They are blank!

Contents of number 5:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://microsoft.com/
```

### Conclusion

There are two key facts to learn here.

1. **File needs to contain a valid "target" (i.e. URL address) and file type name (Internet Shortcut) before the name extension is altered
   (or added).**
2. **Used names cannot be reused for a different target URL. Not even after permanently deleting the original file.**

### Updates

---

It appears that opening the file in Internet Explorer (in case you are using Firefox or another third party browser) once might have the effect of fixing the broken URL file. I have seen it happen here on Windows 8.1 with IE version 11. But as explained before, the URL file content needs to be properly defined before being open in IE. The IE will then reinterpret the content, and even add a nice favicon as a file icon, essentially healing the file by adding any missing "Web Document" property. However, it did not fix my test.url file. So it may not work for all files, and I am not sure why.

---

I found this registry edit to be helpful.

1. Run regedit.exe
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl`
3. Create a new key titled `FEATURE_URLFILE_CACHEFLUSH_KB936881`
4. Navigate to `FEATURE_URLFILE_CACHEFLUSH_KB936881`
5. Create a new dword titled `iexplore.exe`
6. Set value of `iexplore.exe` to 1
7. Reboot

Source: [Microsoft (KB936881)](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/936881)

After doing that, my test.url file *finally* started working, and it received a Firefox icon in place of the globe (see the screenshot in question). This fix originally applied to XP, Server 2003 and Vista. But apparently it works on Windows 8.1 as well (not tested on Windows 10).

The cause for this error – given in the Microsoft KB article – is not very detailed, but it does say following.

> This problem occurs if the Windows shell receives a notification
>   during the process that creates the Internet shortcut file. This
>   notification is received before the file has been completely written
>   to the disk.

It doesn't say what is meant by "notification" exactly.

---

As I suspected, Windows is using some Internet Explorer components to interpret these Internet Shortcut (URL) files. So whatever content you put in that text file is only used for initial interpretation. Once you change the file name extension to URL, you have changed the file association, and thus the file content will get interpreted by Internet Explorer. If properly structured, it will turn it into a working URL Internet Shortcut file. Otherwise (like leaving it empty and changing the extension) you will get the dreaded error when you try to open it.

The actual shortcut is stored elsewhere, not in the file itself, and the original file can therefore be left empty as a 0 byte file once the initial interpretation and file type conversion has been done. The file will only serve the purpose of merely pointing to the shortcut data. The shortcut data being the "Web Document" field which is stored within the NTFS file system.

The whole business with not being able to reuse a file name, or the way that you get that globe thing as your file icon (or favicon, or browser icon), it has to do with the way Internet Explorer caches web content. So in reality, when you double click on one of these URL files, and you have Firefox set as your default web browser, it's really not Firefox that's opening the URL; it's Internet Explorer! It's through some internal Windows wizardry that Internet Explorer then passes the URL to Firefox, Firefox starts and loads the URL and you see the light (*page*). <s>You are left feeling proud about not using Internet Explorer.</s>

To remove any cache that prevents you from renaming the file, or to force Internet Explorer to reinterpret the same file with the same name once more (like after modifying its content), you need to clear out some of the caching folders. This is referred to as TIF or Temporary Internet Files.

1. Open %localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
2. Select all files (ctrl+a).
3. Delete (del)!
4. Yes
5. Try double clicking on your modified URL file now. It should work.

This should work for Windows 8, 8.1 and 10. You will find this folder in other locations in previous Windows versions. In Windows 7 I think it's in the same location as above, up to Windows level. There should be a folder then called Temporary Internet Files.

Comment: If someone knows what part of Windows is responsible for this behavior, and how it can be reset so that file names can be reused for new target URLs, please fill in the gaps. I have yet to find a way to do that. **On that note: I received the latest 10049 of Windows 10 TP today, and in that upgrade process, all the shortcut files above have been reset, such that they are all working now. All except the "Boston" shortcut which was left empty. Number 2, 3 and 6 have also received the SU favicon as a new icon, as part of the reset.**

Comment: [Does Windows cache the contents of .url (Internet Shortcut) files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329139/does-windows-cache-the-contents-of-url-internet-shortcut-files) says MUICache, but I'm not sure since regedit shows nothing .URL-specific there.

Comment: That registry key appears to hold "application company" and "friendly app name" for dll and exe files. I assume it has to do with localization and displaying these names for those who use Windows in a language other than English (hence MUI).

Comment: Like so many times before, Internet Explorer is the culprit for strange behaviors in Windows. Not to mention security problems.

Comment: Congratulations on some in depth sleuthing, and thanks for sharing it here. Nothing you say makes me want to go back to a Microsoft platform. How can they mess it up in so many ways - I never cease to be amazed.

Comment: Like I said before, this is a sorry excuse for a file type. I have a feeling they won't do much about it Windows 10 either. Thankfully they are on the path of (*enlightenment*) removing Internet Explorer altogether. Good riddance! But I'm not sure what to expect of "Spartan". Initially, IE components will be kept for compatibility (mind the many websites that won't even work with anything "less"), but they will get deprecated later on. No riddance after all... probably won't get rid of IE before 2018. Let's hope the install media doesn't get much bigger than 4 GB for Windows 10.

Comment: Now one might be able to modify URL files programmatically by modifying the "Web Document" field. It's a bit extreme but it's probably doable. Or by relying on an old school disk editor. This is like finding a needle in a haystack... blindfolded!

Comment: (1) The URL format is merely a standard INI file; nothing more, nothing less. (2) Obviously leaving it blank won't work; renaming a blank file will not fix that—how could it? (3) Windows caches used URL files in memory, so changes made in a text editor won't be picked up, but changing it in the Properties dialog will send Windows a message to update its cache (rebooting/logging out would also cause Windows to re-read the file from disk). (4) Deleting the file and creating a new one with the same name should work; when you delete it, Windows flags it as gone and flushes it from the cache.